# Google has found malicious software on your page - But I can't find anything suspicious, what should I do?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Toady, I got this error in my Adsense dashboard:

[image]

I have checked that page carefully but couldn't find anything suspicious. What can I do to fix it? This is just a static html page and I haven't even updated it for months.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your hosting environment.

Comment: @Trebor May I ask what kind of hosting information do I need to update to dig into more details? Thanks for the comment.